# What force does a skate boarder rely on to stay on the board?

Tags: forces

What force does a skate boarder rely on to stay on the board?
Im doing a project and need to know the answer to this ASAP.If anyone has any idea please reply.

Comment: There are only three forces on the skateboarder, gravity, the normal reaction with the board, and friction. The skateboarder must use friction to keep the board at the correct position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For which case are you asking? For simply skateboarding along a surface, it is friction that keeps the skateboarder on the skateboard. When performing things like Ollie, the person does not actually stay on the board all through the manoeuvre. Take Ollie for example: the person performs a series of actions which result in an upward movement of the board, which is in turn opposed by the person’s feet thus making it seem like the board is attached to the person while in reality there isn’t constant contact between the two.